# get contents of a div from another website using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yql

what i want to do is that i want to load a particular **div** with a **class="container"** form a site and get its content on my app

i did the ajax call to get a site and load up it's content and got the cross-domain origin error.I donot have access to the server files...it is just some site on the web.

So i looked it up and found the YQL as a good solution to my problem. I want the data in JSON format

i run the following query:

```
select * from html where url="https://in.yahoo.com/"
```

**But when i run the query now i get the entire site including the scripts and css...**

which i don't want..i just want the div..

how do i construct my query then? Or how do i Travers the JSON then

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/prantikv/z7kdno5h/)

Comment: Well, JSON returns a Javascript object. So you can use `.` dot-notation to access the properties: `Object.property.property.property` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to add the xpath to filter your search. For example (taken from yahoo site):

```
select * from html where url='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo' and
xpath='//table/*[contains(.,"Founder")]//a'
```

So you need to add the xpath filter specifying your div.